# Redirect all urls after replace a part of url htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I'm migrating a php script to one server directory to another directory. I tried to write a htaccess rule for that.
the current urls are like below

Ex-

```
    https://www.example.com/scripts/tracking/inex.php
    https://www.example.com/scripts/tracking/agency/invoice.php
    https://www.example.com/scripts/tracking/admin/manage.php
```

The new new urls are like

Ex-

```
    https://www.example.com/dashboard/index.php
    https://www.example.com/dashboard/agency/invoice.php
    https://www.example.com/dashboard/admin/manage.php
```

There have lot of urls like above so it's difficult to write one to one redirects to each urls.

is there anyway to replace **scripts/tracking** part with **dashboard** and redirect to replaced url.

I used this but seems not working

```
    RedirectMatch 301 /scripts/tracking(.*) /dashboard/$1
```

Anyone help me to write this, Thank You

Comment: Is your web server Apache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RedirectMatch permanent "^scripts/tracking/(.*)" "/dashboard/$1"
```

You need mod_alias for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^scripts/tracking/(.*) /dashboard/$1 [L,R=301]
```

You need mod_rewrite for this to work.